Turning tikz frames on and off
Following code formats text with tikz frames ... bordered text AND frame with line for notes.  I want to have pages with normal text ... How can I do this by turning frames on and off?
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper]{book}
% ateb: % ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/726457/
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  inner=2cm,
  outer=10cm,
  top=2.5cm,
  bottom=2.5cm,
}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{mylightGray}{rgb}{41,84,231}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newlength\mlinessep
\newlength\mlinesmargin
\newsavebox\mframetxtbox
\newsavebox\mframedotsbox
\newif\ifmframetxt
\newif\ifmframedots
\AddToHook{begindocument}
{%
  \newlength\mlinelength
  \setlength\mlinelength{\dimexpr\evensidemargin+2.54cm-\mlinesmargin-\columnsep}%
  \newlength\mlinesdrop
  \setlength\mlinesdrop{\dimexpr\topmargin+\headheight+2.54cm+\headsep+\textheight}%
  \newlength\mlinesoddindent
  \setlength\mlinesoddindent{\dimexpr\oddsidemargin+2.54cm+\textwidth+\columnsep}%
  \newlength\mframedrop
  \setlength\mframedrop{\dimexpr\mlinesdrop-0.5\textheight}%
  \newlength\mframetxtoddindent
  \newlength\mframetxtevenindent
  \setlength\mframetxtevenindent{\dimexpr\evensidemargin+2.54cm+0.5\textwidth}%
  \setlength\mframetxtoddindent{\dimexpr\oddsidemargin+2.54cm+0.5\textwidth}%
  \newlength\mframedotsoddindent
  \newlength\mframedotsevenindent
  \setlength\mframedotsevenindent{\dimexpr\mlinesmargin+0.5\mlinelength}%
  \setlength\mframedotsoddindent{\dimexpr\mlinesoddindent+0.5\mlinelength}%
  \newsavebox\mline
  \newcounter{mlinecount}%
  \edef\tempa{\fpeval{\textheight/\mlinessep}}%
  \def\mkint#1.#2nil{#1}%
  \edef\tempb{\expandafter\mkint\tempa.#2nil}%
  \setcounter{mlinecount}{\tempb}%
  \sbox\mline{%
    \hbox to \mlinelength {%
      \leaders \hbox to 0.333em {\hss \textcolor{mlinescol}{.}\hss} \hfill \kern 0pt
    }%
  }%
  \AddToHook{shipout/background}
  {%
    \ifodd\value{page}%
      \multiput(\mlinesoddindent,-\mlinesdrop)(0,\mlinessep){\themlinecount}{\usebox\mline}%
      \ifmframetxt
        \put(\mframetxtoddindent,-\mframedrop){\usebox\mframetxtbox}%
      \fi
      \ifmframedots
        \put(\mframedotsoddindent,-\mframedrop){\usebox\mframedotsbox}%
      \fi
    \else
      \multiput(\mlinesmargin,-\mlinesdrop)(0,\mlinessep){\themlinecount}{\usebox\mline}%
      \ifmframetxt
        \put(\mframetxtevenindent,-\mframedrop){\usebox\mframetxtbox}%
      \fi
      \ifmframedots
        \put(\mframedotsevenindent,-\mframedrop){\usebox\mframedotsbox}%
      \fi
    \fi
  }%
}
% kernel drawing is either 'highly experimental' or produces poor quality results for rounded corners, so use tikz for frames
% to avoid needless overhead, draw the frame only once
\AddToHook{begindocument}{%
  \sbox\mframetxtbox{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center),overlay]
      \node (mframe) [draw=mframecol,rounded corners,text width=\textwidth,text height=\textheight,text depth=0pt] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }%
  \sbox\mframedotsbox{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center),overlay]
      \node (mframe) [draw=mframecol,rounded corners,text width=\mlinelength,text height=\textheight,text depth=0pt] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }%
}
\usepackage{lipsum} % For dummy text
% configuration
% the distance between dotted lines
\setlength\mlinessep{0.2in}
% the distance between the edge of the paper and the dotted lines
\setlength\mlinesmargin{\columnsep}
% frame colour
\colorlet{mframecol}{blue}
% dot colour
\colorlet{mlinescol}{gray}
% frame text?
\mframetxttrue
% \mframetxtfalse
% frame dots?
\mframedotstrue
% \mframetxtfalse


\hyphenation{BAB-Y-LON hea-ven hun-dred mir-a-cles MY-STER-Y Per-gam-os Phil-a-del-Phi-a pro-phe-sy pro-phet-ess pre-pared pow-er them-selves thou-sand three-score thun-der-ings voi-ces}

\setlength{\emergencystretch}{10pt}

\begin{document}


\Large

\chapter*{Sample} 
\lipsum{2}


\end{document}


Follow-on: still while using frames and using book class, I want chapter name as page header

instead of the page number? are all your chapters unnumbered?

is your normal text also two column? or full width?

This provides both commands and a key-value interface to turn frames on and off.
Chapter titles are shown in headers by default in book, so if they do not show up for you, either you are using starred chapters and not issuing marks manually or something in code we've not seen is suppressing them, as they show up OK for me.
Frames are off by default. \FrameOn and \FrameOff turn them on and off. \FrameOn* and \FrameOff* affect the current page only.
Frames may also be switched and and off, as well as configured, using \mframeset{} which takes a key-value list of options, as explained in the code.
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper]{book}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/726457/
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/727946/39222
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  inner=2cm,
  outer=10cm,
  top=2.5cm,
  bottom=2.5cm,
}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{mylightGray}{rgb}{41,84,231}

\usepackage{tikz}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\box_new:N \g_mframe_txt_box
\box_new:N \g_mframe_dots_box
\box_new:N \g_mframe_line_box
\dim_new:N \g_mframe_linelength_dim
\dim_new:N \g_mframe_linesdrop_dim
\dim_new:N \g_mframe_drop_dim
\dim_new:N \g_mframe_linesoddindent_dim
\dim_new:N \g_mframe_dotsoddindent_dim
\dim_new:N \g_mframe_dotsevenindent_dim
\dim_new:N \g_mframe_txtoddindent_dim
\dim_new:N \g_mframe_txtevenindent_dim
\int_new:N \g_mframe_linecount_int
\hook_gput_code:nnn {begindocument} { mframe }
{
  \dim_gset:Nn \g_mframe_linelength_dim { \evensidemargin+2.54cm-\g_mframe_lmarg_dim-\columnsep}
  \dim_gset:Nn \g_mframe_linesdrop_dim { \topmargin+\headheight +2.54cm +\headsep+\textheight}
  \dim_gset:Nn \g_mframe_linesoddindent_dim { \oddsidemargin +2.54cm + \textwidth+\columnsep}
  \dim_gset:Nn \g_mframe_drop_dim { \g_mframe_linesdrop_dim -0.5\textheight}
  \dim_gset:Nn \g_mframe_txtevenindent_dim { \evensidemargin+2.54cm + 0.5\textwidth}
  \dim_gset:Nn \g_mframe_txtoddindent_dim { \oddsidemargin+2.54cm + 0.5\textwidth}
  \dim_gset:Nn \g_mframe_dotsevenindent_dim { \g_mframe_lmarg_dim + 0.5\g_mframe_linelength_dim}
  \dim_gset:Nn \g_mframe_dotsoddindent_dim { \g_mframe_linesoddindent_dim + 0.5\g_mframe_linelength_dim}
  \int_gset:Nn \g_mframe_linecount_int
  {
    \int_div_truncate:nn { \textheight }{ \g_mframe_lsep_dim }
  }
  \hbox_gset_to_wd:Nnn \g_mframe_line_box {\g_mframe_linelength_dim} {
    \leaders \hbox_to_wd:nn  {0.333em} {\hss \textcolor{mlinescol}{.}\hss} \hfill \kern 0pt
  }
}
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \mframe_on:
{
  \ifodd\value{page}
    \multiput(\g_mframe_linesoddindent_dim,-\g_mframe_linesdrop_dim)(0,\g_mframe_lsep_dim){\g_mframe_linecount_int}{\box_use:N \g_mframe_line_box}
    \bool_if:NT \g_mframe_txt_bool
    {
      \put(\g_mframe_txtoddindent_dim,-\g_mframe_drop_dim){\box_use:N \g_mframe_txt_box}
    }
    \bool_if:NT \g_mframe_dots_bool
    {
      \put(\g_mframe_dotsoddindent_dim,-\g_mframe_drop_dim){\box_use:N \g_mframe_dots_box}
    }
  \else
    \multiput(\g_mframe_lmarg_dim,-\g_mframe_linesdrop_dim)(0,\g_mframe_lsep_dim){\g_mframe_linecount_int}{\box_use:N \g_mframe_line_box}
    \bool_if:NT \g_mframe_txt_bool
    {
      \put(\g_mframe_txtevenindent_dim,-\g_mframe_drop_dim){\box_use:N \g_mframe_txt_box}
    }
    \bool_if:NT \g_mframe_dots_bool
    {
      \put(\g_mframe_dotsevenindent_dim,-\g_mframe_drop_dim){\box_use:N \g_mframe_dots_box}
    }
  \fi
}
\NewDocumentCommand \FrameOn { s }
{
  \bool_if:NF \g_mframe_bool
  {
    \IfBooleanT{#1}
    {
      \hook_gput_next_code:nn {shipout/after}
      {
        \bool_gset_false:N \g_mframe_bool
      }
    }
  }
  \bool_gset_true:N \g_mframe_bool
}
\NewDocumentCommand \FrameOff { s }
{
  \bool_if:NT \g_mframe_bool
  {
    \IfBooleanT{#1}
    {
      \hook_gput_next_code:nn {shipout/after}
      {
        \bool_gset_true:N \g_mframe_bool
      }
    }
  }
  \bool_gset_false:N \g_mframe_bool
}
\hook_gput_code:nnn {shipout/background} { mframe }
{
  \bool_if:NT \g_mframe_bool { \mframe_on: }
}
% kernel drawing is either 'highly experimental' or produces poor quality results for rounded corners, so use tikz for frames
% to avoid needless overhead, draw the frame only once
\hook_gput_code:nnn {begindocument}{ mframe }
{
  \hbox_gset:Nn \g_mframe_txt_box
  {
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current ~ bounding ~ box.center),overlay]
      \node (mframe) [draw=mframecol,rounded ~ corners,text ~ width=\textwidth,text ~ height=\textheight,text ~ depth=0pt] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  \hbox_gset:Nn \g_mframe_dots_box
  {
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current ~ bounding ~ box.center),overlay]
      \node (mframe) [draw=mframecol,rounded ~ corners,text ~ width=\g_mframe_linelength_dim,text ~ height=\textheight,text ~ depth=0pt] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
}
\keys_define:nn { mframe }
{
  frame .bool_gset:N = \g_mframe_bool,
  frame .default:n = true,
  frame .initial:n = false,
  frame ~ text .bool_gset:N = \g_mframe_txt_bool,
  frame ~ text .initial:n = true,
  frame ~ text .default:n = true,
  frame ~ dots .bool_gset:N = \g_mframe_dots_bool,
  frame ~ dots .initial:n = true,
  frame ~ dots .default:n = true,
  mlines ~ sep .dim_gset:N = \g_mframe_lsep_dim,
  mlines ~ sep .initial:n = 0.2in,
  mlines ~ margin .dim_gset:N = \g_mframe_lmarg_dim,
  mlines ~ margin .initial:n = \columnsep,
  frame ~ colour .code:n = { \colorlet{mframecol}{#1} },
  frame ~ colour .initial:n = blue,
  dot ~ colour .code:n = { \colorlet{mlinescol}{#1} },
  dot ~ colour .initial:n = gray,
}
\NewDocumentCommand \mframeset { +m }
{
  \keys_set:nn { mframe } { #1 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\usepackage{lipsum} % For dummy text
% configuration
\mframeset{%
%   % defaults shown
%   frame = false, % frames at all?
%   % frame text?
%   frame text = true, % frame text if framing?
%   % frame dots?
%   frame dots = true, % frame dots if framing?
%   % the distance between dotted lines
%   mlines sep = 0.2in, % line separation
%   % the distance between the edge of the paper and the dotted lines
%   mlines margin = \columnsep, % marginal gap
%   % frame colour
%   frame colour  = blue, % frame colour
%   % dot colour
%   dot colour = gray, % dot colour
}


\hyphenation{BAB-Y-LON hea-ven hun-dred mir-a-cles MY-STER-Y Per-gam-os Phil-a-del-Phi-a pro-phe-sy pro-phet-ess pre-pared pow-er them-selves thou-sand three-score thun-der-ings voi-ces}

\setlength{\emergencystretch}{10pt}

\begin{document}


\Large
% see comments
\raggedbottom 

\chapter*{Sample}
\lipsum{1-5}

\chapter{Another}
\FrameOn*
\lipsum{1-5}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Next}
\FrameOn
\lipsum{1-5}
\lipsum[3]

\chapter{Further}
\FrameOff*
\lipsum{1-5}
\lipsum[4]

\chapter{Reaches}
\FrameOff
\lipsum{1-5}
\lipsum[5]

\chapter{Again Frame}
\FrameOn
\lipsum{1-5}
\lipsum[6]

\chapter*{PS}
\lipsum{1-5}

\end{document}

1Tidied up a bit. But I'll delete it, if one of the experts answers, because I can't currently figure out how to get rid of the bad boxes.

you could add \raggedbottom to silence the warnings, you can't justify the page anyway as all the content is boxed so \raggedbottom doesn't make it more ragged, juts adds strech glue to silence the warning

@DavidCarlisle I'm not sure I follow. the dotted lines are boxed, but the text isn't, is it?

well the text in the other column appears boxed, I only had a quick look at the code and I thought you were boxing even if not framing but perhaps not. still \raggedbottom certainly clears the warnings and probably makes sense for this layout
